# Корреляция между тремя переменными в диаграмме рассеивания

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Мне нужно получить такой результат]

[image: Такой результат у меня сейчас]

Мне нужно получить график  корреляции между Возрастом, классом билета и выжившими людьми, но я не понимаю как это сделать, так как там три переменные[image: Вот датасет с которым я работаю]
Код который у меня сейчас:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.scatter(x = dataset['Pclass'], y = dataset['Age'])
plt.xlabel("Pclass", size=15)
plt.ylabel("Age", size=15)
plt.title('Pclass and Age vs Survived', size=18)
ax.grid(axis = 'y')
plt.xticks([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `Seaborn`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

n = 200
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pclass': np.random.randint(1, 4, n), 
                   'Age': np.random.randint(10, 100, n), 
                   'Survived': np.random.randint(0, 2, n)});
sns.swarmplot(x='Pclass', y='Age', hue='Survived', data=df, dodge=True);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]